# React child prop doesn't change when parent state updates

Tags: react-native, state, react-props

I have a react native app and I want to update some states and pass a prop to other components. I am passing the focus state and setFocus to the "Search" component. The focus state on the "Vault" component updates properly but it doesn't affect the "Search" component. The code is like below. What am I doing wrong?

```
const Vault = ({ navigation }: VaultStackNavigationProps<"Vault">) => {
  const [focus, setFocus] = useState(false);

  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerRight: () => (
        <Right isFocus={focus}>
          <Search handleFocus={setFocus} focus={focus} />
        </Right>
      ),
    });
  }, [navigation]);
  return (
    <Box style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "#1A1A1A" }}>
      <Text color="white">hello</Text>
    </Box>
  );
};

export const Search = ({ handleFocus, focus }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const inputRef = useRef<TextInput>();
  const { width } = useWindowDimensions();

  const onHandleFocus = (value) => {
    handleFocus(value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (focus) {
      inputRef.current.focus();
    } else {
      Keyboard.dismiss();

      clearTextState();
    }
  }, [focus]);

  const clearTextState = () => {
    setValue("");
  };
  const onClear = () => {
    clearTextState();
    inputRef.current.clear();
  };

  const onClose = () => {
    onHandleFocus(false);
  };
  return (
    <>
      {focus && (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={onClose}>
          <MaterialIcons name="arrow-back" size={24} color="white" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )}
      {focus && (
        <TextInput
          ref={inputRef}
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            color: "white",
            paddingLeft: 15,
            fontFamily: "CrimsonRegular",
          }}
          onChangeText={(text) => setValue(text)}
          placeholder="Type here"
        />
      )}
      {focus && value.length > 0 && (
        <SearchIconButton
          onPress={onClear}
          style={{ width: width / 9 }}
          icon="close"
        />
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing input state from parent to child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64964992/passing-input-state-from-parent-to-child-component)

Comment: I've already tried it as you can see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your layoutEffect is listening changes only from navigation

Try adding focus to useLayoutEffect array like

```
React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerRight: () => (
        <Right isFocus={focus}>
          <Search handleFocus={setFocus} focus={focus} />
        </Right>
      ),
    });
  }, [navigation, focus]);
```

Comment: It worked but what if I want to use another option in useLayout . Also if I  want to use custom header instead of setting options in useLayoutEffect. It didn't work(I mean focus didn't update in Search component). Can you help for this as well ? Thanks by the way